# How to filter a list where an attribute is variable?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

The title is a bit confusing but I didn't know how else to describe it. My `hostvars` look like this:

```json
{
  "host1": {
    "tags": {
      "Name": "host1-name"
    }
  },
  "host2": {
    "tags": {
      "Name": "host2-name"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know which host I want to capture--I need to get that dynamically based on the results of the `Name` tag. I tried this:

```yaml
hostvars | selectattr("tags.Name", "equalto", "host2-name")
```

But of course the `tags` attribute isn't at the root so it errors out. The problem is the root attribute is variable (`host1`, `host2`, etc.).

I tried to use an asterisk, but I got `"VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'str object' has no attribute '*'"`:

```yaml
hostvars | selectattr("*.tags.Name", "equalto", "AIR-Media-Release-SW5")
```

So how would I filter based on the `Name` tag, where I don't know what the root attribute is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `selectattr` filter is meant for list of dicts. You are trying to apply it to `hostvars` which is not a list but a dictionary.

To perform your search you'll first need to transform that dict to a list. There are basically two options to do this:

1. Pass the var to the `dict2items` filter to get a list of key/value pairs (i.e. `key=host_name_string, value=dict_of_host_variables`)
2. Completely drop the keys and keep only the values (i.e. the dictionary of the actual vars for the host).

The solution to choose depends on your requirement. I this example I'll take the second one as we will not loose any information. In fact the key we will drop will still exist inside the value as the `inventory_hostname` variable.

Here is how to filter your hosts with this solution:

```yaml
matching_hosts_list: "{{ hostvars.values() | selectattr('tags.Name', "==", "AIR-Media-Release-SW5") }}"
```

From there you can use the result as you wish. For example, to print a list of matching host names:

```yaml
- name: Show matching host names
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: matching_hosts_list | map(attribute='inventory_hostname')
```